# ¿Cómo inserto dos campos al mismo tiempo en una tabla MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, php5

Tengo una tabla MySql con las siguientes columnas;  id, nombre, apellido, dirección, estatus y observación. Ya existen los registros correspondientes a cada columna a excepción de los campos "estatus" y "observación", a continuación dejo el código que muestra todos los registros de dicha tabla llamada "alumno"

```
<body>
    <div>       
        <table border=3>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Apellido</td>
                    <td>Direccion</td>
                    <td>Estatus</td>
                    <td>Direccion</td>
                    <td>Observar</td>
            </tr>
                <?php
                    include("conexion.php");
                
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM alumno";
                    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
                    while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['apellido'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['direccion'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['estatus'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['observacion'];?></td>

                    <td><a href="VerAlumno.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="btn1">Observar</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

al dar clic en el boton "observar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Redirecciona a otra pagina en la que se muestran todos los datos del "alumno" seleccionado sin que se pueda modificar alguno de estos, pero aquí existe un "textarea" llamado **observación**, un botón llamado "rechazar" y un boton llamado "aceptar", a continuación el código de esto;

```
 <body>
    <?php
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    
        include("conexion.php");
        
        $query="SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE id='$id'";
        $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
        $row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
    ?>
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
            <label>Nombre del alumno</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" disabled value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>">
            <br>
            <label>Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" disabled value="<?php echo $row['apellido'];?>">
            <br>
            <label>Direccion</label>
            <input type="text" name="direccion" disabled value="<?php echo $row['direccion'];?>">
            <br>
            <label>Observacion</label>
            <textarea name="observacion" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
        </form>

        <a href="RechazarAlumno.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="btn">Rechazar</a>

        <a href="AutorizarAlumno.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="btn">Autorizar</a>

    </div>
</body>
```

el resultado de este codigo es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al dar clic en el botón "rechazar" redirecciona a otra pagina, en la que en el campo "estatus" se inserta la palabra "rechazado" al mismo tiempo se imprime un mensaje para hacer saber que se rechazo el alumno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuación el código de esto:

```
<body>
    <?php
      include("conexion.php");

      $conf = new Configuracion();
      $conf->conectarBD();
     
      $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
     
      $query="UPDATE alumno SET estatus = 'Rechazado', observacion = '$observacion' WHERE id='$id'";
      $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
    ?>
    
  <div>
    <h2>Se rechazo el alumno</h2>
    <br>
    <a href="Administrador.php" id="btn">Volver a los alumnos</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

El resultado de esto es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que que yo quiero hacer es que al mismo tiempo de rechazar al alumno también se inserte en el campo **observación** de la tabla MySql lo que se ingreso en el **textarea**, pero al dar clic en el boton "Rechazar" me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parcer el script **RechazarAlumno.php** no tiene definida esta variable, la pregunta es ¿como definir la variable del "textarea" llamada **observacion** al script **RechazarAlumno.php** para que pueda guardar este campo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando mal el formulario, pues por un lado lo defines como formulario mediante el elemento `<form>` pero por el otro no lo usas como tal al no tener un botón tipo **submit** ni un **action** que apunte al script **RechazarAlumno.php**.

Mejor hazlo así:

```
 <body>
    <?php
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    
        include("conexion.php");
        
        $query="SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE id='$id'";
        $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
        $row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
    ?>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" action="RechazarAlumno.php">
            <label>Nombre del alumno</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" disabled value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>">
            <br>
            <label>Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" disabled value="<?php echo $row['apellido'];?>">
            <br>
            <label>Direccion</label>
            <input type="text" name="direccion" disabled value="<?php echo $row['direccion'];?>">
            <br>
            <label>Observacion</label>
            <textarea name="observacion" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Rechazar">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Y en RechazarAlumno.php hazlo así:

```
<body>
    <?php
      include("conexion.php");

      $conf = new Configuracion();
      $conf->conectarBD();
     
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $observacion = $_POST['observacion'];
     
      $query="UPDATE alumno SET estatus = 'Rechazado', observacion = '$observacion' WHERE id='$id'";
      $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
    ?>
    
  <div>
    <h2>Se rechazo el alumno</h2>
    <br>
    <a href="Administrador.php" id="btn">Volver a los alumnos</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Cambios realizados

1. Agregado el action en el elemento `<form>` apuntando a RechazarAlumno.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="RechazarAlumno.php">
```

2. Dentro del elemento **form** se ha agregado un input con **name="id"** del tipo `hidden` conteniendo el valor del id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

3. Dentro del elemento **form** se ha agregado input tipo `submit`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Rechazar">
```

4. Eliminado enlace anterior apuntando a RechazarAlumno.php
5. En el script *RechazarAlumno.php* se ha modificado la forma de recoger los datos de *$_REQUEST* a *$_POST* y se ha agregado una variable para recoger el campo **observacion** a guardar también:

```
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $observacion = $_POST['observacion'];
```

6. En la consulta **UPDATE** se ha agregado consecuentemente la nueva variable para actualizar la columna **observacion**:

```
$query="UPDATE alumno SET estatus = 'Rechazado', observacion = '$observacion' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Ya nos diras si te ha funcionado.

Comment: De la manera en que lo planteas en tu respuesta funciona bien, pero lo que pasa es que en el formulario donde con el **action** apuntas al script **RechazarAlumno.php**, en este formulario tengo otro botón de "aceptar alumno", entonces si lo hago como me lo dices en tu respuesta no voy a poder poner agregar este botón ya que el submit solo va a apuntar a **RechazarAlumno.php**, la pregunta es ¿Como me traigo el campo "textarea" al script **RechazarAlumno.php** sin agregar el **action** al formulario? Muchas muchas gracias por responder y espero me puedas ayudar, Saludos!! :D

Comment: Ponlo tal como lo tienes en la pregunta, pues si no das toda la información vamos a ciegas y te damos respuestas que no te sirven, como esta mia. Puedes editar tu pregunta agregando la información completa pulsando sobre el enlace **Editar** que aprece en el pie de la pregunta.

Comment: Recién edite mi pregunta y agregue algunos detalles mas como es la consulta **UPDATE** que me proporcionaste, ahora solo es cuestión de definir la variable **observación** en el script **RechazarAlumno.php** para que no me muestre el error y pueda guardar lo que se ingrese en el "textarea" ¿Cómo defino esta variable en este script?

Comment: A ver, varias cosas... 1) Gracias por actualizar la pregunta 2) Mi respuesta, **si te la lees completa y la aplicas completa**, sigue siendo válida, porque no afectaria al otro enlace que has puesto ahora apuntando a `AutorizarAlumno.php`, el cual queda fuera del <form> y de hecho, tanto le da estar dentro como estar fuera, pues es un mero enlace externo realizado con `<a>`.  3) El nuevo error que tienes ahora de $observacion es porque no te has leido mi respuesta ni mi código completo, donde verás que defino `$observacion` **antes** del UPDATE.  Léetela con detenimiento y aplicala bien.

Comment: Gracias por darle seguimiento a mi pregunta, ya implemente tu respuesta tal cual en mi código y ya funciona correctamente, me quedo con la duda si se puede hacer como yo lo pretendía al comienzo?, sin que el **action** del formulario apunte al script **RechazarAlumno.php**? y sin el **submit** conservando el enlace externo **<a>** de "Rechazar". Al parecer solo tenia que definir la variable **observacion** en el script **RechazarAlumno.php** la pregunta es **¿Cómo traigo la variable "observacion" en el script "RechazarAlumno.php" sin el action del formulario?**

Comment: Entiendo que ese campo **observacion** lo quieres modificar antes de pulsar **Rechazar**, por eso lo del formulario de mi respuesta es la mejor opción. Aún así, ya que insistes en tu pregunta de hacerlo **sin el action**, también lo podrias hacer mediante **ajax** o javascript, pero eso ya implicaria todo un nuevo código en javascript el cual queda fuera de la respuesta porque no lo has intentado previamente de ese modo. Busca información y ejemplos en javascript sobre **fetch** o **ajax** e inténtalo si quieres, y si te surgen problemas haces una nueva pregunta con tu nuevo código en js.